# OS error - 11:Try again

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, в начале создания приложения сделал БД в дальнейшем понадобилось к ней обратиться и получаю ошибку " нет столбца CollectionId " версию бд менял не помогло. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема
За ранее спасибо

БД

```
public static String TABLE_NAME = "CollectionPhoto";
    public static String COLLECTION_ID = "CollectionId";
    public static String FILE_NAME = "FileName";
    public static String FILE_NAME_SAMPLE = "FileNameSample";
    public static String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("create table " + CollectionPhotoTable.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + "_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + CollectionPhotoTable.COLLECTION_ID + " text,"
                + CollectionPhotoTable.DESCRIPTION + " text,"
                + CollectionPhotoTable.FILE_NAME + " text,"
                + CollectionPhotoTable.FILE_NAME_SAMPLE + " text);"
        );
    }
```

Место ошибки

```
public Cursor cursor(String _collectionId) {
        return GlobalVars.db.rawQuery("select * from CollectionPhoto where CollectionId = ? ", new String[]{_collectionId});
    }
```

DBhelper

```
void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    CollectionPhotoTable.createTable(db);
    }
 static void deleteTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists CollectionPhoto");
        db.endTransaction();
    }
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        createTables(db);

    }
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        deleteTables(db);
        createTables(db);
    }
```

Error

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: CollectionId (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from CollectionPhoto where CollectionId = ?, (OS error - 11:Try again)
```

Comment: Судя по сообщению об ошибке, у тебя не MySQL, a SQLite. Список меток поправлен.

Comment: Не надо собирать запрос в `db.execSQL`. Собери в дополнительной переменной. И покажи, что получилось.

Comment: _"версию бд менял не помогло"_ - а надо было вызывать метод `createTable` либо описывать обновление БД в методе `onUpgrade`.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev
это всё есть

Comment: Значит это применялось не правильно, или не своевременно! Сначала нужно написать код, после менять версию БД, а не наоборот. И транзакция без `setTransactionSuccessful()` не имеет никакой пользы.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev сперва был написан код проверен , была переделана бд , изменена версия бд 
А за `setTransactionSuccessful()` спасибо